# Turn of sudo (root privileges) for single subroutine

Tags: c, matlab, root, sudo

I have compiled a c-code calling a Matlab script with the MEX compiler. 
The plan is to call this function using system("./CCodeWMatlab") inside a main()

First when I tried calling this function I got the error: "error while loading shared libraries: libeng.so". 
However this was fixed by adding: " export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/matlab71_sv/bin/glnxa64/ to .bashrc."

Running ./CcodeWMatlab in terminal works. However if I try to type sudo ./CcodeWMatlab I get the same error as first time: " "error while loading shared libraries: libeng.so".

In Main() there are subroutines that needs to be run as root. It is therefore not an option to run this without sudo. What I need is a way to turn of root privileges for a part of my code, most preferably for one subroutine.. Is this possible?

Comment: You have to set the environment variables when calling sudo. explained here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/57915/environment-variables-when-run-with-sudo

Comment: executing a user program with super user privileges is never a good idea. What kind of subroutines that need root access are you talking about?

Comment: I am creating a PID-regulator to a model-ship which I control with Phidget hardware. The functions sending and receiving data from the hardware via USB needs root acces

Comment: then you should probably separate out the part that drives the hardware into a daemon-like process that communicates with the rest of your program by pipes or sockets.
I repeat: running user programs with super user privileges is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few things:

- `sudo -E ./CcodeWMatlab` to ask `sudo` to preserve your whole environment.
- `sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./CcodeWMatlab` to only preserve that environment variable.

These are not guaranteed to work - you might need to disable resetting the environment in your sudo configuration file(s).

Comment: This might be a "derp" question, but where should I add this? I am rnning the program with sudo ./main    Should i put this inside the system("./Ccode) part?

Comment: That would only work if your main program was running as root too. Try the above when running your main program.

Comment: First one got same error, had some hopes for the last line, but now I get the error: "License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -9
Your username does not match the username in the license file." Ill try to do a workaround with my  license ;)